# Hive command runs only in the directory apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/bin

Tags: hadoop, hive

I installed Hadoop and Hive on ubuntu in pseudo distributed mode.Now I noticed that hive command runs only when my current working directory is apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/bin.Otherwise it always gives me error like :

FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

The tutorial which I am following is using cloudera and there I have noticed that he is able to run hive commands from almost any directory.

I want to understand the reason behind this behaviour.I am new to hive and hadoop